# Scaled Bitmap print on PDF without loosing Image Quality in Android Studio

Tags: android

**Requirements** :- I need to print images on a PDF document (A4 size sheets).
**Source** :- I got the images through the Camera and from the Gallery.
**Crop** :- I just used UCROP for cropping and editing the image if it necessary as an option.

**Problem** :- ***I can do everything mentioned above without any error and result also very good. But I need those print on a A4 size sheet as a PDF Document. To do that, I had to scaled down those Bitmaps to match the required sized. But the thing is, when I do that the Image Quality of the Scaled Bitmap on PDF is very low and can't read the details correctly.***

[Screenshot of a Sample PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSDCk.jpg)

Please help me to get success on this issue.
Your kind reply are mostly welcome and highly appreciated.

```
//boolean img1_SetImage - used to check Img1 is available or not
//img1_Uri - Uri of Img1
if (img1_SetImage) {
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img1_Uri.getPath(), opt);
int[] xyImg = xy(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 298, 175);

PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo2 =
                    new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page myPage2 = myPDFDoc.startPage(myPageInfo2);
Canvas myCanvas2 = myPage2.getCanvas();

Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, xyImg[0], xyImg[1], false);
myCanvas2.drawBitmap(scaledBmp, xyImg[2], xyImg[3], new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
bmp.recycle();
scaledBmp.recycle();
}


private int[] xy(float width, float height, float left, float top) {
    int finalWidth, finalHeight, finalLeft, finalTop;
    float wScale, hScale, scaleFactor;
    wScale = (436 / width);
    hScale = (270 / height);

    if (wScale >= hScale) {
        scaleFactor = hScale;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = wScale;
    }
    finalWidth = (int) (width * scaleFactor);
    finalHeight = (int) (height * scaleFactor);
    finalLeft = (int) (left - (finalWidth / 2));
    finalTop = (int) (top - (finalHeight / 2));

    int[] returnValues = {finalWidth, finalHeight, finalLeft, finalTop};

    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: To help people answer your question it is recommended that you show the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks mate. I just add it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of scaling the bitmap before adding I scale the pdf canvas before adding the bitmap at original resolution, this produces good results for me as the pdf scales it down (the original bitmap inside the PDF is the higher quality image)

Below is your code adapted to use the method I use.

```
//boolean img1_SetImage - used to check Img1 is available or not
//img1_Uri - Uri of Img1
if (img1_SetImage) {
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img1_Uri.getPath(), opt);

PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo2 =
                    new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page myPage2 = myPDFDoc.startPage(myPageInfo2);
Canvas myCanvas2 = myPage2.getCanvas();

// Work out scaleFactor to get all the image on the page
float wScale, hScale, scaleFactor;
wScale = (float) 595 / bmp.getWidth(); // If you don't cast Int/Int = Int so you loose any decimal places.
hScale = (float) 842 / bmp.getHeight();  // Alternative is to define the size as float e.g. 842.0f
if (wScale >= hScale) {
        scaleFactor = hScale;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = wScale;
    }



Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
myCanvas2.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
myCanvas2.drawBitmap(bmp,0,0,paint);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Idea is clear and I think it will works, but the thing is above code doesn't gave the result what we expected. PDF page will not scaled back to A4 size with its content. If we can 1) add the image with as it is and then 2) PDF page scaled back to A4 size with the image, then we can get success.

Comment: This process of scaling the page canvas works for me, I did not check your scaleFactor calculations, in my App that does this just scales the width of the bitmap so it fits the width of the A4 PDF (the height is controlled when generating the bitmap). The only thing I can think of is you might need to cast the scaleFactors to floats otherwise the division will be done as an Int before it is cast to the float (I've updated the example for this). You can check if this is happening for you by logging the scaleFactor

Comment: Yes I noticed that and cast it already. Everything is clear except one. How can I scaled down the PDF page with the page content. I can set the w/h of the canvas according to the Bitmap and print it on the PDF. Then image quality will stay as it is. but how can I scaled down the PDF back to A4 sheet size. If I can do that, problem may be solved. Thanks.

Comment: T H A N K S   M A T E. It works.....

Comment: Please mark it as answered as it works, The image is stored in the PDF at the original size as an Xobject, then the PDF Content object scales it to place it on the page.
I found https://superuser.com/a/1361536 to explain it more